# Notification of facebook comment replies

Tags: facebook, notifications, comments

I have searched high and low for an answer without any luck.

Here is my situation:

I have set up fb comment box on my website.

When anyone makes on comment on my website, I am notified in my personal profile, the notification takes me straight to the comment moderator tool, where I can see the comment and and find out which page on my website has been commented.

All that seems to be working ok.

What is not working is, when I reply to a comment made on my website, the person that made the original comment is not receiving a notification of my reply.

Is this a function that is not available?

If it is available where can I find the information to implement it ?

If people are not receiving notifications of my replies, one they could think that I am rude, second it defeats the whole object of creating engaging threads on the website.

Thank you so much, I have been trying for months to find this answer.

Susanna

Comment: Known bug I just discovered https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/306791559425667?browse=search_51b672c71c97c9c87330804

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem as of 2017. It seems that the only way is to tag a person in a reply for her to receive a notification.